# Can't Install Ubuntu on my laptop

Tags: boot

When I boot ubuntu, after selecting the language, I Click Install Ubuntu along with windows 7 and the computer just restarts. From youtube videos I cannot go to the section where you select the size for the ubuntu OS.
I have 50gb windows 7 (c: drive) and 2 ntfs partitioned drive on windows 7

Comment: It would be helpful to include the version of the Ubuntu distro.

Comment: You'll indeed need to add more info as we have no clue on how you're installing, what version you're installing, how you've prepared it... etc.

Answer (score 0):

Installing ubuntu along side windows 7 is not a very safe idea on a long run. I had to pay heavily this July for this mistake. Instead, boot up in Windows 7. Delete one of those ntfs partitions in device manager, this will be shown as free space while ubuntu installation stage. Select "Do something else" option instead of "Install Ubuntu along with windows 7". In the next section, select that partition which is shown as free space. Use 5 to 10 GB in that for ubuntu swap area and the remainder for / (logical partition, ext4 file system). This is the cleaner method, which I follow nowadays successfully.

Comment: So i will select the deleted drive and format that 5-10 gb and choose swap and the remaining format it to ext4 type and just continue?.. i mean there are several option while formatting like.. boot location, make this bla bla bla etc.?

Comment: Ok I will get back to you with exact details